# Dynamically building a list which need an event listener. onClick is stripped out when rendered. What other options are there?

Tags: reactjs

ReactJS question: I'm building a list dynamically from a JSON object. each list item would typically have an onClick event, which I type in during the loop. However, when React renders this, the "onClick" is gone. Something like vanilla JavaScript's ".addEventListener" would be great. However, that doesn't seem to be an option in ReactJS. What are my options when a class is clicked in ReactJS that does not have the standard inline listener?

I'm not using the Bootstrap JS at all.

What I write in JavaScript:

```
    for (let i = 0; i < listNames.length; i++) {
      nameList =
        nameList +
        "<a href='#modal-" +
        listNames[i] +
        "' class='list-group-item list-group-item-action' data-toggle='modal' onClick={this.showListModal.bind(this, "+i+")} >" +
        listNames[i] +
        "</a>";
    }
```

---

My "onClick" event is gone when React renders it:

### Dynamically built list

```html
<div class="list-group">

<a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" data-toggle="modal">List Item 1</a>
<a href="#modal-List Item 2" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" data-toggle="modal">List Item 2</a>
<a href="#modal-List Item 3" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" data-toggle="modal">List Item 3</a>

</div>

</div>
```

Comment: `onClick` is React/JSX property, but you are creating HTML string so it should be `onclick` if using `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` - if using something else, it's up to the "something else" to decide which attributes are supported

Comment: instead of outputting a string. just actually use JSX for what it is there for. react can render arrays of elements just fine

Comment: This content is being built prior to rendering. The JSON is being built from a CMS form during "edit mode".

Comment: please see [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: So the user gets to choose what kind of content they want in a bootstrap row with a limit of 4 columns. Their options are text, single or multiple images in a carousel, single or multiple videos in a carousel or a list, where each item is clickable and will bring up the modal with details. When I find out what type of content they want I wrap the appropriate html around the values they submitted which have been  stored in json. The image urls and videos id's are in arrays. The text and the list options are stored as strings with the actual bootstrap html included.

Comment: Here is a walk through of the CMS building the json and seeing the rendered html, which stripped out the "onClick":https://youtu.be/uyKWfGUZv50

Comment: {this.state.sectionOne.length > 0 ? (
          <div className="album py-5" data-section="sectionOne">
            <div className="container">
              <div className="row">
                {this.state.sectionOne.map((content, i) => {
                  return (
                    <div className={"col-md-" + this.state.sectionOneColNum}>
                      {ReactHtmlParser(content)}
                    </div>
                  );
                })}
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        ) : null}

Answer (score 0):

You can use the onClick from React to trigger a function that will change a state to show the modal!
Would be something like that:

```
const List = (props) => {
    const [modal, updateModal] = useState(false)

    return (
        datas.map((d, i) => (
            <a onClick={() => updateModal(!modal)}>List Item {i}</a>
        ))
    )
}
```

Comment: I appreciate it. However, it's not that the modal wouldn't show. The problem is the "onClick" is being stripped out  of the string when rendered in the JSX.